# RoboVM Error: Couldn't launch iOS simulator

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, jvm, robovm

Error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.robovm.rt.bro.Dl.open(Ljava/lang/String;)J
>       at org.robovm.rt.bro.Dl.open(Native Method)
>       at org.robovm.rt.bro.Runtime.getHandle(Runtime.java:260)
>       at org.robovm.rt.bro.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:187)
>       at org.robovm.rt.bro.Bro.bind(Bro.java:56)
>       at org.robovm.objc.ObjCRuntime.(ObjCRuntime.java:43)
>       at org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject.(ObjCObject.java:57)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

What could be the reason? I'm using the latest libGDX version(1.6.4) and the above project is a sample project I just created to test RoboVM.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Solved it and here is the solution:

1. Remove the 'html' part from the settings.gradle file.
2. In build.gradle file, remove the section project(":html") completely. Keep other sections intact.
3. Edit Run configrations and add new Robovm iOS configuration.
4. Save, sync with gradle, clean and build. Run on the newly created RoboVM run config.

Comment: What do you mean by "sync with gradle" in step 4? How exactly is it done?